# Angularjs - ui-calendar : how to refresh events

Tags: angularjs, ui-calendar

I am using ui-calendar. I need to make a call to the server to retrieve all my events in order to display them on a calendar.
Here is what I do :

Controller:

```
vm.propositionsToCome = PropositionsAffairePresentationToCome.get(function(result){
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        $scope.events.push({title: 'test'+i,start: result[i].datePresentationPartenaire});
    }
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events]
    uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar'].fullCalendar('refreshEvents');     
  });

$scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header:{
          left: 'title',
          center: '',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        lang: 'fr'
      }    
    };


$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

HTML :

```
div class="calendar" ng-model="events" calendar="myCalendar" config="uiConfig.calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>
```

eventSources is well filled, when I display it in the view I am getting :

> [[{"title":"test0","start":"2016-06-20T22:00:00.000Z","_id":1},{"title":"test1","start":"2016-06-20T22:00:00.000Z","_id":2}]]

But no events display on my calendar. I don't know how to refresh the calendar once I have loaded all my  events from the server.

How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

I use this function for it:

```js
function refreshEventsInCalendar() {
        var arr = $scope.events.slice(0, $scope.events.length);
        
        $scope.events.splice(0, $scope.events.length);
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            $scope.events.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
```